# Didn't understand ,expected shape=(None, None, 1100), found shape=(1, 29907, 1), Confusion about LSTM input shape? (the data is genome sequence)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

My data is about genome sequence, basically a long string of "AAATTGCCAA...AA". Total data is 1100 means there is a total of 1100 rows and each row's length is 29907  [Here is a pic of my dataFrame](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QpqQJ.png). And there is a total of 5 target values.

I converted the data into a NumPy array of float values.
The shape of my data is `train_data.shape: (1100,29907)`. Here, how is my data look after I convert it into NumPy array is given below:

```
array([[1.  , 0.25, 0.25, ..., 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.75, 0.5 , 0.5 , ..., 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [1.  , 0.75, 1.  , ..., 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       ...,
       [0.5 , 0.25, 0.75, ..., 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [0.5 , 0.25, 0.75, ..., 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ],
       [1.  , 0.75, 1.  , ..., 0.  , 0.  , 0.  ]], dtype=float32)
```

We know that the LSTM input requires a 3D or 2D shape `(batch_size, time_steps, seq_len)`.

So I reshape the data

```
train_data=train_data.reshape(1100,29907,1)
```

Now, when I pass the data into my model, my input shape is `input_shape=(29907,1100)`.

The actual model is given below. But when I run the model it gives me a value error, which is
`ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer sequential: expected shape=(None, None, 1100), found shape=(1, 29907, 1)`.

I didn't get the error, did my input shape is wrong or the reshaping is wrong? Plus I have used a conv1D in the second layer, Does the shape also have to compatible with both (LSTM and conv1D) layers? In the LSTM layer, I define there will be 5 output `(units-5)` as there are 5 target values.

```
def create_model():
    
    num_classes = 5
    model = Sequential([
    LSTM(units=16, input_shape=(train_data.shape[1],train_data.shape[2]), 
    activation='relu', return_sequences=True,  
    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001)),
    Dropout(rate=0.5),
    Conv1D(filters=100, kernel_size=21, strides=1,
    padding="same",activation='relu'),
    Dropout(rate=0.3),
    MaxPooling1D(pool_size=148, strides=1, padding='valid'),
    Dropout(rate=0.1),
    # LSTM(16,activation='relu'),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(5, activation='softmax')
    ])

    # compile the model
    model.compile(loss="sparse_categorical_crossentropy", optimizer=Adam(learning_rate= 0.0001),
              metrics=['accuracy'])

    return model
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1D convolution on sequences expects a 3D input whereas the LSTM you are using outputs a 2D array`(batch_size, units)` as the argument `return_sequences` is set to `False`. This argument tells whether to return the output at each time step instead of the final time step. Changing it to `True` returns a 3D array`(batch_size, time_steps, units)` instead of a 2D array.

```
LSTM(units=5, input_shape=(29907,1100), activation='relu', return_sequences=True, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001))
```

Also just a small thing but don't hardcode the input shape, instead set it to something like `input_shape=(X_train.shape[1],X_train.shape[2])`.

Edit:

So in addition to that you would need to expand the dimension of the last channel before passing it to the model, reshape it using this method.

```
# train_data shape: (1100,29907)
train_data = np.expand_dims(train_data, -1) # new shape = (1100,29907,1)
```

**Do not reshape it like this**, you could easily make an error with the number of values in any of the channels:

```
train_data=train_data.reshape(1100,29907,1)
```

Then just change the input shapes of the LSTM to the 2nd and 3rd channels of the input data.

```
num_classes = 5
model = Sequential([
    LSTM(units=num_classes, input_shape=(train_data.shape[1],train_data.shape[2]), 
    activation='relu', return_sequences=True, 
    kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(0.0001)),
    Conv1D(filters=100, kernel_size=21, strides=1,
    padding="same", activation='relu',
    Dropout(rate=0.5),
    MaxPooling1D(pool_size=203, strides=1, padding='valid'),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(num_classes, activation='softmax')
])
```

Comment: Thanks for clearing the misconception, I change the `return_sequence` value to `True`. Now, the program is running, let's see the result. By the way, I have something to ask is about the model and the accuracy? The thing is do we need to create a complex model to increase accuracy or just a simple model like this one would do? In my dataset, the data is 29907 long and there are 1100 rows, for that reason, I can't increase the dataset also there is RAM issue. So what can I do to increase the accuracy? @yudhiesh

Comment: Great to hear that please do accept and upvote the answer. Hmm I would actually classify an LSTM as a complex model, maybe use Logistic Regression(a single model for each class) first before diving into complex models. I wouldn't look at accuracy for this kind of model. Accuracy is calculated using `TP + TN TP + TN + FP + FN`,  where false positives increases accuracy score, instead look at `F1-score` or `ROC-AUC`. Then, if the performance is not satisfactory look at tuning the hyperparameters. But this is entirely dependent on whether the model is overfitting or underfitting.

Comment: I didn't notice that you write different code in the second line. `input_shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2])` your second line actually means (29907,1), but in the first line, you write that the value will be (29907,1100). Yesterday I ran the code but 3hours elapsed and not a single epoch hasn't been done, so I came here to recheck the answer. After correcting the code it shows me `ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer sequential: expected shape=(None, None, 1100), found shape=(1, 29907, 1)` how do change this shape or fix it. @yudhiesh

Comment: @Mahfuz could you include the code for preprocessing the data as well as the shapes of `X_train`?

Comment: I include the code for preprocessing the data as well as the `X_train` before and after shape, in my code the `X_train` is `train_data`.  @yudhiesh

Comment: @Mahfuz could you check the updated answer?

Comment: Yeah, I think in your edited code the input_shape is wrong, I think you want to write this line `input_shape=(train_data.shpae[1],train_data.shpae[2])`.  And I reshape the data as you told me. But it shows me a value error `ValueError: Shape mismatch: The shape of labels (received (1, 1)) should equal the shape of logits except for the last dimension (received (1, 29907, 5))`. The shape of my `train_labels: (1100,)` as there are a total of 1100 datasets. @yudhiesh

Comment: @Mahfuz are you using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` for the loss function? It should be `categorical_crossentropy`.

Comment: Yes, I am using `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` because there is a total of 5 classes or unique integer label in my whole dataset. `df['variant_label'].unique() :  [0,1,2,3,4]`, or should I use `categorical_crossentropy`! (https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-choose-loss-functions-when-training-deep-learning-neural-networks/) from this website I learn that I should use `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` , can you please explain me why should I use `categorical_crossentropy`?   @yudhiesh

Comment: **Check my previous comment also**. From that website I learned that I shouldn't use `categorical_crossentropy` if my dataset is not `one_hot` encoded, so that's why I used `sparse_categorical_crossentropy`. Though I change the loss function as you told so, it still shows me a value error: `Shapes (1, 1) and (1, 5) are incompatible`.  @yudhiesh

Comment: Please include all the code for modelling @Mahfuz

Comment: I don't know maybe there is some minor mistake in my code, but now it's running. Also with `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` the code executes. By the way thanks for all the time you gave me and one more thing I am replying you late because the code is still running from yesterday. The accuracy meter is not good it's been 17 epochs but the training accuracy didn't cross 70 yet and the validation accuracy is 59, clearly the model overfit the problem, so, now I have a problem with the model, I added more dropout, but still, it overfits. What should I do and I added the updated model @yudhiesh

Comment: @Mahfuz yes as your labels are not one-hot encoded then `sparse_categorical_crossentropy` is correct. Ok so I wouldn't use accuracy for the reasons I mentioned earlier instead F1-score would be a better choice. I would start with simplifying the model, use `32` filters in the `Conv1D`,  pool_size of `4` for MaxPooling1D, set rate to be `0.5` for all Dropout layers and try using [EarlyStopping](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/callbacks/EarlyStopping). Please do accpet and upvote the answer. If you need more help on improving the model create a new question.